# iOS Push Notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) - Invalid Registration Token Issue

Tags: ios, node.js, server, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm encountering a challenge with implementing **push notifications on iOS using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)**. While Android notifications are working correctly, I'm facing difficulties when sending notifications to iOS devices.

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```js
let sendNotification = (fcm, data) => {
  const options = {
    priority: 'high',
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24,
    mutableContent: true,
    contentAvailable: true
  };

  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title:  `John just joined`,
      body: `Your friend John is now on your app`,
      sound: 'default',
      badge: `1`
    },
  };

  messaging.sendToDevice(
    fcm,
    payload,
    options
  ).then(function(response){
    console.log(`✅ Successfully sent message: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
    return true;
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('❌ Error sending message:', error);
    return false;
  });
}
```

The error I'm encountering is:

> ✅ Successfully sent message: {"results":[{"error":{"code":"messaging/invalid-registration-token","message":"Invalid registration token provided. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with FCM."}}],"canonicalRegistrationTokenCount":0,"failureCount":1,"successCount":0,"multicastId":5714268513970227000}

I've ensured that all Firebase Console settings, including Key ID, Team ID, and the certificate, are correctly configured. The FCM token for iOS (**FAE728F3A519B6688733E9AEE3DFE3266CA2F88683C49BC5E85F24984DF2BF1C**) is being used.

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this "Invalid registration token" issue specifically on iOS.

Comment: Problem fixed,  I used apn instead of firebase-admin for the iOS push notification.